# how do I disable canOpenURL? I don't want my UIWebView to open up the official app

Tags: ios

Is there a way to disable the url scheme in iOS?

My app has a UIWebView that opens up a certain website. If the user has the official app installed it opens it up and breaks my workflow.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use a `UIWebViewDelegate` to listen for:

`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

Return `NO` for those URLs.